# Youtube Video feeds link not working

Tags: iphone, rss, youtube-api

I am using following link to get list of youtube video for given `string` in my iOS app.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=10&alt=rss&q=Hello
```

Previously it was working fine, but now its not giving me any response at all.

Anyone please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has stopped this API, you have to migrate to data API Version 3.0
check the link below for more details

http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2015/04/bye-bye-youtube-data-api-v2.html